# Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, guava

I have a problem with android studio, **when I add guava-18.jar lib and run** my Main I get an Error:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.>
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I try to add this in build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true
}
```

but do not resolve.

Please help me!!!

my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.unical.mat.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
 compile files('libs/activation.jar')
 compile files('libs/gdata-analytics-2.1.jar')
 compile files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')
 compile files('libs/gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar')
 compile files('libs/jsr305.jar')
 compile files('libs/mail.jar')
 compile files('libs/guava-18.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: in gradle file u need to add  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gradle File need add **"com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0"** This Packeage

in Activity need to update

```
 MultiDex.install(this);
```

Refer this site 
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html